# Is there a piecewise graph that is not a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I just thought about this when I saw a problem asking whether the given three equations combined to describe a piecewise graph is a function. I forgot the equations but does such piecewise graph that's not a function exist? If so, can we determine it using the usual vertical line test?

Comment: Can you define what a piecewise graph is?

Comment: Well, it is a combination of sub-graphs described by intervals (sub-domains). Am I right?

Comment: I mean, as long as the intervals are non-overlapping, and each interval contains a function, then the piecewise function made by combining the functions over each interval is also a function.

Comment: @DonThousand so for example the graph of y = (x, x ≥ 0), (2x, x > 0) is not a function because the intervals overlap?

Comment: On overlapping intervals, the corresponding functions must agree on the overlap. In your example, they do not.

Comment: @harpey1111 Definitions aren't "right" or "wrong". They can be *suggestive*, or *surprising*, or *insightful*, or *counterintuitive*, or *incomplete*, or *imprecise*, or *misleading*, or *inelegant*, or *superfluous*. But no one can tell you what you mean when you talk about piecewise graphs. If you want to talk about combinations of sub-graphs described by intervals, that is your right.

Comment: Oh. let me put it this way, is this a function, y = (-x^2, x<0), (√(-x), x ≥ - 4)—sorry about my format.

Comment: You mean $$y = \begin{cases} -x^2, & x < 0\\ \sqrt {-x}, & x \ge -4 \end{cases}$$ Ask yourself, what is the value of the function at $-2$? A function is just a "machine" for turning input values into output values. It's one rule is that if you put the same input value in several times, you will get the same output value every time. With this example is that true? If you put in any value where subdomains overlap, what value do you get out?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define two separate constant functions on overlapping real intervals, and try to combine the functions and their graphs.

- Define $f:[0,3]\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=0$.
- Define $g:[1,4]\to\mathbb R$ by $g(x)=1$.
- Let $F$ be the graph of $f$, namely $F=[0,3]\times\{0\}=\{(x,0):x\in[0,3]\}$.
  (Some authors may identify $f$ with $F$, but we will not.)
- Let $G$ be the graph of $g$, namely $G=[1,4]\times\{1\}=\{(x,1):x\in[1,4]\}$.

Having distinguished between these objects, we can ask a few different questions.

**Question 1.** Consider the union of the two graphs, $F\cup G$. This is a perfectly nice subset of the plane. You can draw it without any difficulty. But is it the graph of a function? **No**, because it fails the vertical line test. The vertical line at $x=2$ intersects $F\cup G$ at two points: $(2,0)$ and $(2,1)$.

**Question 2.** Consider combining the functions $f$ and $g$ "piecewise", like so:

$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in [0,3]\\ 1, & x \in [1,4] \end{cases}$

Is $h$ a function? **No**, and in fact the situation is much worse than that: $h$ is not a well-defined object at all. The notation that we used to try to define $h$ doesn't make any sense.

**Question 3.** Is $F\cup G$ the graph of something like a function? Yes, it is the graph of the *set-valued function* $h:[0,4]\to2^\mathbb R$ defined by

$h(x) = \begin{cases} \{0\}, & x <1 \\ \{0,1\}, & x \in [1,3] \\ \{1\}, & x > 3 \end{cases}$